# how to retrieve img from MySQL into pictureBox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want get an image from a `Blob` in MySQL then display image in a PictureBox. My incoming image is not correct and I don't understand how I can retrieve the byte array because my current array is not correct.

My code:

**add img into database**:

```
using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
     if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
         imageUrl = ofd.FileName.ToString();
         //roundPictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
         roundPictureBox2.ImageLocation = imageUrl;
         MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         con.Open();
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO reg.img_table(image, id) VALUES (@image, @id)", con);
         long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
         Properties.Settings.Default.idImg = id;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytes);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
     }
}
```

**return Img**:

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

**main code**:

```
private void photoLoad()
{
    string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;" +
                     "port=3306;" +
                     "database=reg;" +
                     "username=root;" +
                     "password=Admin123";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    byte[] ImageByte = new byte[0];
    string query1 = "select image from reg.img_table where id= @id";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Properties.Settings.Default.idImg);
    
    try
    {
         con.Open();
         MySqlDataReader row;
         row = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         while (row.Read())
         {
             ImageByte = (Byte[])(row["image"]); 
         }

         if (ImageByte != null)
         {
             // You need to convert it in bitmap to display the image
             roundPictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(ImageByte);
             roundPictureBox1.Refresh();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Error Img");
    }
}
```

An error doesn't show. The login form shows but PictureBox doesn't show the photo.

Comment: `var image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom((byte[])row["image"]);` -- You should show how the Image bytes got into the database. See whether the method used to get the Image bytes looks like: `var bytes = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo([Some Image], typeof(byte[]));` or `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes([The Image File path ]);` -- What is the *error in debugging THERE*?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName));

Comment: when adding img to database no error

Comment: What happens if you change the code in `cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageBytes", MySqlDbType.Blob, [The bytes].Length).Value = [The Image Bytes];`? Or `cmd.Parameters.Add("?imageBytes", ...).Value = ...`?

Comment: I do not understand you. 
What do you want to say ? 
I'm not passing the data to the database correctly?

Comment: No better way to know it than testing it.

Comment: i add a picture exactly like you wrote but i still don't understand how to display it in pictureBox

Comment: 1) Add the code you used to save the Image bytes to the question. 2) First snippet in my first comment. 3) You still haven't specified what *error in debugging HERE* means. If you have an exception, post that, too.

Comment: You should also verify your use of `LastInsertedId`, since that's related to an `AUTO_INCREMENT` Column (it's also specific to a Connection).

Comment: I have  Auto incremental into DB. I am sure that I am passing the data to the database correctly

Comment: An `AUTO_INCREMENT` Column increments the value itself. You may use the last inserted `ID` as the FK in another Table (and have procedures in place to not let it become orphaned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your OP, you're storing your image in a database BLOB column in a MySql database. The following shows how to insert an image into a MySql database table. Then retrieve that image and display it in a PictureBox.

**Download/install NuGet package**: `MySql.Data`

**Database Table**: Student

[image]

I've chosen to store the connection string for the database in `App.config`.

**App.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=University123;Uid=testAdmin;Pwd=password123;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**Create a class**: (name: HelperMySql.cs)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...**

**Add the following using statements**:

- using System.Configuration;
- using System.IO;
- using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

**HelperMySql.cs**

**Note**: I've chosen to use `LongBlob` instead of `Blob` - this can be changed, if desired.

```
public class HelperMySql
{
    private string _connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    //private string _connectionStr = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=University123;Uid=testAdmin;Pwd=password123;";

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlText)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionStr))
        {
            //open
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
            {
                //execute
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string filename)
    {
        //reads image from file and returns as byte[]

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new Exception("Error (GetImageAsByteArray) - Filename not specified.");
        else if(!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new Exception($"Error (GetImageAsByteArray) - File '{filename}' doesn't exist.");
        
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    }


    public void TblStudentCreate()
    {
        //for mySQL, use backticks (ex: `First Name`) if tablename has space in it
        string sqlText = @"CREATE TABLE Student (Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                                       FirstName varchar(50),
                                                       LastName  varchar(75),
                                                       Img longblob,
                                                       CONSTRAINT PK_Student_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID));";

        ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText);

        Debug.WriteLine("Info: Table created (Student)");
    }

    public void TblStudentInsert(string firstName, string lastName, string filename)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new Exception("Error (TblStudentInsert) - Filename not specified.");
        else if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new Exception($"Error (TblStudentInsert) - File '{filename}' doesn't exist.");

        byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

        TblStudentInsert(firstName, lastName, imageBytes);
    }

    public void TblStudentInsert(string firstName, string lastName, byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Student (FirstName, LastName, Img) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @imageBytes);";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionStr))
        {
            //open
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
            {
                //add parameters

                //FirstName
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;

                //LastName
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                
                //Img
                if (imageBytes != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageBytes", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = imageBytes;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageBytes", MySqlDbType.LongBlob).Value = DBNull.Value;

                //execute
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetStudentImage(int id)
    {
        string sqlText = "SELECT img from Student where Id = @id;";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionStr))
        {
            //open
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;
                
                //execute
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while(dr.Read())
                        {
                            //get image from database and return as byte[]
                            if (dr["Img"] != null && dr["Img"] != DBNull.Value)
                                return (byte[])dr["Img"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**: Insert Record to Database

```
private HelperMySql helper = new HelperMySql();
                 ...
helper.TblStudentInsert("John", "Smith", @"D:\Images\Students\JohnSmith.png");
```

**Usage**: Display Image in PictureBox (name: pictureBox1)

```
int studentId = 1;
byte[] imageBytes = helper.GetStudentImage(studentId);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; //fit to size
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

**Note**: You may consider storing the filenames in the database, and store the actual files in the file system instead.

**Resources**:

- [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/)
- [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)