# Invalid MySQL Query Syntax

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, mariadb

What's wrong with my code? It keeps on showing this error, and fails to extract any entry from the database

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Private Async Sub connDatabase()
    searchDrop.Text = ""
    searchValue.Text = ""

    If tableTypeLabel.Text = "pis" Then
        sqlQ = "SELECT CAASN, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Occupation, Platoon, CAA_Company, Status FROM @tabNam;"
    ElseIf tableTypeLabel.Text = "dlt" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Info not available")
        Me.Close()
    End If

    dataTab.Rows.Clear()
    dataTab.Columns.Clear()
    Try
        Await sqlConn.OpenAsync()
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlComm.CommandText = sqlQ
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabNam", companyTagLab.Text)
        sqlAdap = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlComm.CommandText, sqlConn)
        val = sqlAdap.Fill(dataTab)
        Await sqlConn.CloseAsync()

        If val > 0 Then
            listFilt.DataSource = dataTab
            listView.DataSource = Nothing
            listView.Rows.Clear()
            listView.Columns.Clear()
            listView.DataSource = listFilt
        ElseIf val < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data not available!")
        End If

        dataTab = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not possible to bind the table name using a SQL prepared statement.

Comment: I first tried doing it with variables then this method, but both still show that error...

Comment: If you want to build your query using a table named stored in a variable, then you will have to use string concatenation.  But note that concatenation and SQL queries are basically not a good combination.

Comment: That still won't work... I already tried concatenating the query with a string variable, and the error shows...

Comment: `and the error shows` ... what is that error?

Comment: The stack.imgur address... I tried editing it to become a link, but stack overflow overreacts to the post being mostly code...

Comment: Error clearly shows dbms is Mariadb, so please use Mariadb as the tag (not MySQL)

Comment: But the library I used for this is named "MySQL Connector"... I'm kinda confused about why would a connector for MySQL use MariaDB... Is there a big difference between the two?

Comment: *"I already tried concatenating the query with a string variable, and the error shows"*. Then you did it wrong. If you actually show us what you did then maybe we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: This is how I concatenated my query: "SELECT CAASN, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Occupation, Platoon, CAA_Company, Status FROM " & companyTagLab.Text  ---   I already tried adding a space, and a semicolon at the end, and it still didn't work...

Comment: According to this [article](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/getting-started/what-is-mariadb/): _MariaDB is a fork of MySQL_ and according to this [post](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/): _MySqlConnector is an ADO.NET data provider for MySQL, MariaDB, Amazon Aurora, Azure Database for MySQL and other MySQL-compatible databases._.  The following may be useful: [Migrating from Connector/NET](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/)

Comment: I recommend separating the database code from code that interacts with the UI. MessageBox is blocking and shouldn't be used in that method. You may consider changing it to a function that returns the number of rows affected. Additionally, the connection should be closed when execution exits the method. Consider using a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Comment: You've include the column names in the SQL query. It doesn't make much sense to have a table name that can be changed. If you've designed your database properly, there shouldn't be another table with those exact column names. If for some reason you feel that the column names should be duplicated, please add your table definitions to the post so they can be examined. Try the SQL query with the table name as part of the SQL query (without any string manipulation/concatenation) and see if it works. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71540398/10024425) may be helpful (it's in C#).

Comment: The following may be useful: [Description of the database normalization basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description). Search for `database normalization` for additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this string:

```
"SELECT CAASN, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Occupation, Platoon, CAA_Company, Status FROM @tabNam;"
```

Drop the parameter, and change it to:

```
"SELECT CAASN, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Occupation, Platoon, CAA_Company, Status FROM " & companyTagLab.Text
```

**Make sure `companyTagLab.Text` doesn't leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks!**