# How to use MySQL variables in a VB.NET query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When using a query with MySQL variables from VB.NET I get an error

`Fatal error encountered during command execution.`

The problem is when trying to use a MySQL variable like `@sum` in a VB.NET string, this variable is recognized as a parameter of the MySqlCommand and not as part of the string itself.

Here is the code that I use.

```
dim query as string = "SET @sum = 0; SELECT @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from cccustomers WHERE customer = 443"
using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    end using
end using
```

I also tried this with exactly the same result:

```
dim sums as string = "@sum"
dim query as string = "SET " & sums & " = 0; SELECT " & sums & " := (" & sums & " + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from cccustomers WHERE customer = 443"
```

And I also tried this:

```
dim query as string = "SET @sum = 0; SELECT @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from cccustomers WHERE customer = 443"
using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sum", "@sum")
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    end using
end using
```

But in this case, the problem is that it passes me the variable as a string with quotes `'@sum'` and that gives a different error in the query.

If I make that same query directly in phpmyadmin it works correctly, the problem I have is: How can I use the MySQL variable in VB.net?

I need the variable because in each line I have to show the accumulated balance and not only show the balance of each particular line.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Table Definition, Sample Data and expected Output

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `debe` double NOT NULL,
  `haber` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `stack`
--

INSERT INTO `stack` (`id`, `debe`, `haber`) VALUES
(1, 100, 0),
(2, 100, 0),
(3, 100, 0),
(4, 100, 0),
(5, 0, 50),
(6, 100, 0),
(7, 0, 150),
(8, 100, 0),
(9, 100, 0),
(10, 100, 0),
(11, 0, 100),
(12, 100, 0);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `stack`
--
ALTER TABLE `stack`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `stack`
--
ALTER TABLE `stack`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
COMMIT;
```

The Query: (works on PhpMyadmin but **NOT WORK** on VB.NET because the symbol `@` in `MySqlCommand` expects a parameter - I don't want to send a parameter, **I want to Send a MySql variable**)

```
SET @sum = 0; 
SELECT debe, haber, @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from stack;
```

Expected output:

[image: Query Results on PhpMyAdmin]

Code on VB.NET with the SAME QUERY:

```
dim query as string = "SET @sum = 0; SELECT debe, haber, @sum := (@sum + debe - haber) AS 'Saldo' from stack;"
using con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    end using
end using
```

Result on VB.NET

[image]

This exception means that `@sum` is expected to be defined as a `parameter`, but I don't want to define a parameter, I want to declare a **MySQL variable**.

Comment: VB.NET is not phpMyAdmin. Start by clearly identifying what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: The following is in C#, but should also be easy to understand for VB.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71540398/10024425. In the C# code, `!` can be replaced with `Not` (VB.NET) and `!= null` can be replaced with `IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: @user09938 inneed to use MySQL’s variables inside VB.NET code. I know that vb.net and PhpMyAdmin are not the same, I just exemplified that this query worked in phpmyadmin. The problem is: to identify a MySQL variable I must use the symbol @ and that is interpreted by vb.net as a parameter

Comment: Please add table definitions, sample data, and expected output to your post.

Comment: @user09938 I have edited my question as you recommended