# How Can i install MySQL in visual studio 2022

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, connector

I'm working on a VB project with visual studio 2022. I tried to connect it with my database in wampserver. I import MySQL using 'imports MySQL.Data.MySqlClient' but MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand and MySqlException are undefined. I tried to install MySQL connector 6.9.8. but I doesn't work with vs 2022. It works only with vs 2012.I tried many méthods but it doesn't work. Is there any solution with vs 2022
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have wampserver but i can't connect my VB project with m'y database. I import MySQL using 'imports MySQL.Data.MySqlClient' but MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand and MySqlException are undefined

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71540398/10024425 - it's in C#, but should be easy to convert to VB.NET.