# How Can i connect VB.net (visual studio 2022) to database

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, mysql-connector

I'm working on a VB project with visual studio 2022 VB.Net 6.0. I tried to connect it with my database in wampserver. I import MySQL using 'imports MySQL.Data.MySqlClient' but MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand and MySqlException are undefined. I tried to install MySQL connector 6.9.8 but it doesn't work with vs 2022. It works only with vs 2012.I tried many méthods but it doesn't work. Is there any solution working with vs 2022 .net o framework. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOdJUMlc4ZM

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538778/how-to-retrieve-img-from-mysql-into-picturebox/71540398#71540398