# connection class with SelectCommand.parameters.AddWithValue queries

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqlclient, sqldataadapter

The method for retrieving data from a connection class was decleared as

```
public void retrieveData(string command)
```

The SqlDataAdapter as

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, conn);
```

How do i execute my queries with `SelectCommand.parameters.AddWithValue` like the example below?

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select count (*) from login2 where UserName =@user and PassWord =@pass", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", hp.HashMe(txtPassword.Text));
```

Do i need another method to handle the SelectCommand.parameters.AddWithValue? Do i modify the retrieveData method to handle it? How do i do this?

When i created the object of the class with the SelectCommand.parameters.AddWithValue i got an error that says its not valid in this context

```
CONN inputdata = new CONN();
inputdata.ExecData("insert into login2(UserName,PassWord,Name) values(@user,@pass,@name)");
inputdata.ExecData.SelectedCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtRUser.Text);
```

Comment: What is this `CONN` class and why do you have it? Why don't you just do like the example: `using var connnection = new SqlConnection (.....); using var da = new SqlDataAdapter...` Or use a command and reader directly. or even better, switch to an ORM like Dapper or Entity Framework.

Comment: CONN is the name of the connection class. I have several forms that needs to access the database and i dont want to be repeating the connections codes over and over again

Comment: OK but you need to pass through parameters to this `ExecData` function. Also I hope you are disposing your connection correctly with `using`.

Comment: I cannot access parameters with my class but without the class it works well.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0),  however, using _AddWithValue_ can make it difficult to debug. I recommend using _Add_ instead.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid i think i have to redeclear the SqlDataAdapter as so SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters,conn);

Comment: The following may be of interest: [SqlDataAdapter (SqlCommand)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqldataadapter-ctor(system-data-sqlclient-sqlcommand))

Comment: Try nesting the following statements. _SqlConnection_, _SqlCommand_, _SqlDataAdapter_. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71540398/10024425), although for mySQL, shows how to nest the commands - it's the same for SQL Server.